# Measuring the angles between 2 vectors

Tags: vectors

Inorder to take the angle between 2 vectors, both vectors should diverge or converge at  a single point.why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Angle between two vectors is related to the dot product of one vector on another and their magnitudes as

$$\cos\alpha = \frac{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}}{|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|}$$

so you take a projection of one on another since your aim is to find the angle. You can't define the projection properly without having them at a single point.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors are usually depicted as arrows in diagrams, this is misleading as vectors  exist at a point in space, not as a line. When you talk about the angle between two vectors those vectors must be defined at the same point. If this is not the case then it doesn't really make sense to talk about the angle between them. This is not usually a problem in physics as you're usually talking about vector fields that are defined everywhere in space, you can then talk about the angle between two vector fields as a scalar quantity defined everywhere.